# Why is the console only printing one match id in the function I created

Tags: python

I wrote the following function to download different match data from a videogame API. However, when I want to print out the json file of one of those, I can't and in the end it only prints the same match id of the very first match id I manually gave.

This is my code:

```
import requests, json, time, os

#Download games
def get_match_by_id(match_id):
  m_id = str(match_id)
  #fetch match data
  response = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/" + m_id)
  if response.ok:
    print("GET:", m_id)
    data = response.json()
    #save the match data
    file = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Win Probability Prediction/downloads" + os.sep + m_id + '_data.json', 'w')
    json.dump(data, file)
    file.close()
    
match_id = 6727193237
match_id = 6757193237
for i in range(0, 5000):
  get_match_by_id(match_id + 1)
  time.sleep(2)
```

And the results are all invariably:

```
GET: 6757193238
```

Also to add that, there is no content being dumped in the downloads folder I have selected.

Comment: Is this code correct `get_match_by_id(match_id + 1)` ? You might want to add `i` instead of `1`

Comment: This is correct. How can I mark your response as solution?

Comment: I could type out an answer, but I would say this is more of a typo issue, so you can feel free to close/delete the question yourself. If you want me to write out an answer, let me know.